# How to retain the Active Tab in Bootstrap 5 after post back or page refresh on ASP.NET am using button control instead of a tag

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

How to retain the Active Tab in Bootstrap 5 after post back or page refresh on ASP.NET
am using button control instead of a tag

Answer (score 0):

you can simply run the javascript method after postback and set the active tab.